# "Switch" function in another switch function in java

Tags: java, list, switch-statement

I've been trying to make a program like a menu where you can select what you want to do with switch function. But in case 1 , case 2 and case 3 I want to make another "switch" functions.The problem is I don t know how to back to main menu "switch(exercitiu)" from case 1,2 or 3 after I add element/remove element /modify element from my lists.

"INVALID ENTRY" means nothing but to complete the case.

case 1 , case 2 and case 3 are list(Cours , Profesor, Student) based.

```
public class Clase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("   ALEGE EXERCITIUL:\n0.Pentru a iesi \n1.Adauga/Sterge/Modfica un curs     \n2.Adauga/Sterge/Modifica un student  \n3.Adauga/Sterge/Modifica un profesor  \n4.Raporta toti studentii inscrisi la un curs    \n5.Raporta toate cursurile \n6.Ca un profesor sa poata nota un student \n7.Raporta notele tuturor studentilor \n8.Raporta media notelor studentilor la un curs \n9.Raporta media notelor date de un profesor");
        int exercitiul = input.nextInt();
        do {
            switch (exercitiul) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Alege: \n0.Iesi in meniul de exercitii \n1.Adauga curs \n2.Sterge curs \n3.Modifica curs \n4.Vezi lista cursurilor");
                    int ex1 = input.nextInt();

                     if(ex1==1){
                            ManagerCursuri.AdaugaCurs(cursuri);}
                    else if(ex1==2){
                            ManagerCursuri.StergeCurs(cursuri);}
                    else if(ex1==3){
                            System.out.println("INVALID ENTRY");}
                    else if(ex1==4){
                            System.out.println(cursuri);}
                    else if (ex1==0){exercitiul=input.nextInt();}
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Alege: \n0.Iesi in meniul de exercitii \n1.Adauga student \n2.Sterge student\n3.Modifica student \n4.Vezi lista studentilor");
                    int ex2 = input.nextInt();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Alege: \n1.Adauga profesor \n2.Sterge profesor\n3.Modifica profesor \n4.Vezi lista profesorilor");
                    int ex3 = input.nextInt();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("INVALID ENTRY");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("INVALID ENTRY");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("INVALID ENTRY");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("INVALID ENTRY");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    System.out.println("INVALID ENTRY");
                    break;
                case 9:
                    System.out.println("INVALID ENTRY");
                    break;
                default:
                    if (exercitiul != 0)
                        System.out.println("~Comanda invalida!~Alege un numar din lista enumerata mai sus!~");
                    else
                        System.out.println("Multumesc pentru rularea programului :)");
            }
        }
        while ((exercitiul <= 0) && (exercitiul >= 9));


    }

}
```

Comment: *FYI:* `switch` is not a *function*, it's a *statement*.

Comment: maybe the down-votes are rather furious because of language issues. you could try to type the question in your native language and have it translated by google translate. look: poate că voturile negative sunt destul de furioase din cauza problemelor lingvistice. ați putea încerca să tastați întrebarea în limba dvs. maternă și să o traduceți prin google translate.

Comment: A nice way to deal with such menu stuff would be to use a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the java feature called 'labels':

```
thisIsALabel:
switch(outer) {
case 1:
    switch(inner) {
        case 1:
            break thisIsALabel;
        case 2:
             break;
    }
    System.out.print("Hello!  ");
}
System.out.println("Bye!");
```

Calling the above with `outer = 1, inner = 2` will print: `Hello!  Bye!`. Calling it with `outer = 1, inner = 1` prints just `Bye!`, because it is interpreted as breaking the switch statement at the same level as the label you specified, i.e. the outer 'switch' (a labelled break or continue breaks all constructs until you get to the targeted one, and then breaks/continues that one).